# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

i am inserting some data to an salesforce object named as Application__c from php using Soapclient. After connection successfull, i have written following code

```
$applications = array();
    $updateFields = array();

                if($_POST['savingsAccountBankName'] != ''){
                    $updateFields['savings_account_bank_name__c']= $_POST['savingsAccountBankName'];
                }
if($_POST['AutoMake'] != ''){
                    $updateFields['Auto_make__c']= $_POST['AutoMake'];
                }
                if($_POST['AutoLicense'] != ''){
                    $updateFields['Auto_license__c']= $_POST['AutoLicense'];
                }
$sObject = new sObject();
            $sObject->type = 'Application__c';
            $sObject->fields = $updateFields;
            array_push($applications, $sObject);


            try {
                $results = $sforceClient->create($applications,'Application__c');
                foreach ($results as $result)
                {
                    $errMessage = $result->errors->message;
                    echo $errMessage;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Salesforce Upsert Error. Please try again later.';
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($e);
                echo '</pre>';
            }
```

i am getting error "Trying to get property of non-object" at line "$errMessage = $result->errors->message;". What is the problem?

thanks

Comment: Either `result` or `errors` is not an object. What does `sforceClient->create()` return? Basically, `$results` should be an array of objects which have `errors` property which is again an object with `message` property.

Comment: What php tells you is that either `$result` is not an object or `$result->errors` is not an object. Since this a SOAP thingy, it's possible that `$result->errors` is actually an array that holds message objects. Try `var_dump($result); var_dump($result->errors);` to see with what your are dealing with;

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that ***$result*** is an array..

Try this :

```
if (!isset($result[0]->success) || ($result[0]->success!=1)) {             

    $strErrCode = isset($result[0]->errors[0]->statusCode)?
                        $result[0]->errors[0]->statusCode:'CANNOT_INSERT';
    $strErrMsg = isset($result[0]->errors[0]->message)?
                       $result[0]->errors[0]->message:'Error Trying to insert';
    $arrResult = array(
                       'errorCode' => $strErrCode,
                       'errorMsg' => $strErrMsg,
                       'id' => '',
                      );
    error_log( 'Error Trying to insert  - [' . $strErrMsg . '] - [' . $strErrCode . ']');   
}
if (isset($result[0]->success) && ($result[0]->success==1)) {               
    $arrResult = array(
                       'errorCode' => 'SUCCESS_INSERT',
                       'errorMsg'  => 'Insert Success',
                       'id'        => isset($result[0]->id)?$result[0]->id:'1',
                      );

     error_log( 'Success insert - [' . (isset($result[0]->id)?$result[0]->id:'1') . ']');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that whatever $results contains, it is not an  object. Try doing a var_dump() on the variable $results and see what is actually in there. Then you can properly reference it.

Comment: $results = $sforceClient->create($applications,'Application__c');
    print_r($results);                                                     its showing output as                                                                   stdClass Object ( [id] => a0DZ00000008dUOMAY [success] => 1 )
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\bakul_project\insertToApp.php on line 287

Comment: object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["id"]=> string(18) "a0DZ00000008dUTMAY" ["success"]=> bool(true) }
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\bakul_project\insertToApp.php on line 289